# Negative values in interpolation, 'A value in x is below the interpolation range'

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate some data on gravitional waves.
I am getting ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range.

My code is:

```
obs_wave['time (s)'] = obs_wave['time (s)']-1205951542.153363 #shift time so merging event@ t=0 
tmin = -0.042
index = np.where((obs_wave['time (s)']>= tmin) & (obs_wave['time (s)'] <= 0 ))
obs_wave = obs_wave.iloc[index]
f = interp1d(obs_wave['time (s)'], obs_wave['strain'])
xnew = np.arange(tmin, 0, 0.01)
ynew = f(xnew)   
plt.scatter(xnew, ynew, 'o')
plt.show()
```

The values for x are negative, could this be causing the error?
Thanks.

Comment: The error means exactly what it says - you are attempting to use *interpolation* but the value you are trying to interpolate is outside the range that the interpolation model is aware of. If it is outside the range you need some form of extrapolating the value, for example through regression.

Comment: You can see that my data in obs_wave has been restricted to tmin to 0, likewise the limits on the x values are from tmin to 0. Why is it still throwing up an error?